# Bind '<' key in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, key, bind

It's a simple question, there is a way to take the ASCII code of a character to bind or anything else? I searched for aswners before making the question

Answer (score 1):

To bind to `<` you need to bind to the event `<less>`.

A handy trick to know what to bind to for some of the more unusual keys is to write a program that displays the keysym of every key you press. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, width=20, height=2, font=("Helvetica", 24))
label.pack(fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)
root.bind("<Any-KeyPress>",
          lambda event: label.configure(text=event.keysym))
root.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```